# expressing 'not possible that'

Tags: grammar

> kono team ga makeru (hazu ga nai / wake ga nai).

Which one is correct?
How do we differentiate the use of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ~makeru wakeganai translates to "there is no way they will lose"
- ~makeru hazuganai translates to "they probably wont lose/they shouldn't lose"

  So differentiating them depends on what you want to say. ~makeru kanousei (可能性）ha hikui would be another, albeit colder, way to say that there is a low probability of them losing.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and the wake version is stronger. (The ga after team is very natural. <s>The subject in a sub-clause is basically denoted by ga.</s> Or rather any combinations of "kono team ga/ha makeru hazu ga/ha" can work in many situatoins. <s>[edit] The usual wa/ga theory cause a mental breakdown to those insubstantial noun structures because "hazu" is the subject in terms of syntax while it's semantically more like a part of the predicate.</s>It seems idiomatic in the negative form.)